# Draw a rectangle with pixi.js

Tags: pixi.js

[Chrome v32]

How to draw a basic RED rectangle with PIXI.js library ?

I tried this (not working)

```
var stage = new PIXI.Stage(0xFFFFFF);
var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(400, 300);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);
renderer.render(stage);
var rect = new PIXI.Rectangle(100, 150, 50, 50);
stage.addChild(rect);
```

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method
>   'setStageReference'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Geometries are not renderable, they are for doing geometric
>   calculations.

[Source](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/2374-primitives-circle-rectangle-not-working/) @xerver

So we have to use `PIXI.Graphics()`

Answer (score 75):

You can't render geometry (`Pixi.Rectangle`), they are meant for calculations only. You can do the following instead:

```
var graphics = new PIXI.Graphics();

graphics.beginFill(0xFFFF00);

// set the line style to have a width of 5 and set the color to red
graphics.lineStyle(5, 0xFF0000);

// draw a rectangle
graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 300, 200);

stage.addChild(graphics);
```

<sup>[source](http://www.goodboydigital.com/pixi-webgl-primitives/)</sup>

Answer (score 13):

There is a nice way to do this using `PIXI.Texture.WHITE`.

```
const rectangle = PIXI.Sprite.from(PIXI.Texture.WHITE);
rectangle.width = 300;
rectangle.height = 200;
rectangle.tint = 0xFF0000;
stage.addChild(rectangle);
```

Comment: That's indeed pretty nice

Comment: What's the trade off? Or difference? Performance impact?